# Split a query string by "&" but some attribute has this "&" in the value

Tags: javascript, split

I try to split an query by "&", but some attribute also has this "&" in the value, may I know how to split it? For example:

```
const query = "attr1=value1&attr2=va & lu&e2&attr3=value3"
```

May I know how to split the query into an array without splitting the "va & lu&e2":

```
["attr1=value1", "attr2=va &%lu&e2", "attr3=value3"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are talking about url query parameters then "lu" and "e2" are two separate query parameters... Why do you expect them to be together in that case?

Comment: Any literal `&` characters should be encoded as `%25`. If there is an actual `&` sign, it's a query parameter.

Comment: Hi @Jesse, could you please explain the "%25"? Also, if value 2 has a "%" it will cause URIError:URI malformed error if I use encodeURIComponent. May I know how to solve both issues? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use these parameters on a query,
you should use encodeURIComponent() which will escape the string so it can be used as a value in a query.

```
const query = "attr1="  + value1 + 
    "&attr2=" + encodeURIComponent("va & lu&e2") + 
    "&attr3=" + value3
```

This will result in the following string:

```
"attr1=value1&attr2=va%20%26%20lu%26e2&attr3=value3"
```

So every '&' is encoded as '%26'

To split it you can now rely on the '&' sign:

```
const splitArray = query.split('&')
```

Although, I would use the encodeURIComponent() for every query parameter value. unless I know exactly which value I use and that it doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Hi @Gal Weiss! Thank you so much! I have another question if using encodeURIComponent, if value 2 has "%" in it, like value2 = "va & lu&e2 is 100% perfect" , this % in the value 2 will cause URIError:URI malformed error, may I know how to use it with "%" in the value?

Comment: @Ying This answer answers that exact question. You encode it. Refrain from asking questions in comments.

Comment: Hi @Jesse, I so I tried this methods with:const query = "attr1="  + "value1" + 
    "&attr2=" + encodeURIComponent("va% & lu&e2") + 
    "&attr3=" + "value3";
const splitArray = query.split('&'), however the result of the second one is "attr2=va%25%20%26%20lu%26e2", but how can I get "attr2=va% & lu&e2"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could mark & differently when you are using it as a value: something like & for example and then create your own function for splitting.

like:

```
var acc = query[0];
var splitted = [];
for(let i = 1; i < query.length; i++) {
    if(query[i] === '&' && query[i-1] !== '\') {
        splitted.push(acc);
        acc = "";
    } else {
        acc += query[i];
    }
}
```

the code probably does not work, but hopes this can clarify something